# How to save an object on application close

Tags: android

I have an object an object that I'm trying to save. I've successfully saved the object by calling the following method `save()` on the object whenever I change the state of the object.

```
public void save() {

    String fileName = "MyObject";

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = ctx.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(this);
        objectOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, it's becomes tedious calling the `save()` method every time the object state changes. I would simply like to save the object when the application is closed, and call `save()` just once versus mutiple times each time I change the state of the object.

Now I've read there are various ways to define "closing the application" and I've gone ahead and reviewd the application life cycle [diagram](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity). It seems to me there are two methods `onPause()` and `onStop()` which are called in the following order.

> onPause() when the system kills the app when it's in the background
>
> onStop() --> OnDestroy() when the user kills the app

So I imagined that by overriding `onPause()` and `onStop()` and calling `save()` in both of these methods, I would have saved the object I'm trying to save in every conceivable scenario in which the app is closed or killed somehow.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myObject.save();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    myObject.save();
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be the case, and my object is not being saved. Is my my understanding of the app life-cycle incorrect or is my code perhaps bugged somewhow?

Comment: How did you know that the object is not being saved?

Comment: I don't, I haven't actually checked, but I can tell from the behavior of my application that the object is not being loaded, however I will verify to make sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done should work as far as I see. Saving in `onStop` is nevertheless useless because `onPause` is systematically called first.

Are you sure you recall what you saved in `onResume`?

Comment: Thanks, but I figured out my problem. My object was in fact being saved, but one of it's variable's variable's did not implement `Serializable` ... As regards to your advice, I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777559/how-to-save-an-object-on-application-close/41777778#41777778) that `When you application needs to save some persistent data you should always do it in onPause() method and rather than onStop(). Because if android OS kills your process then onStop() and onDestroy() methods are never called. Similarly retrieve data in onResume() method.`

Answer (score 0):

I figured our my own problem. Yes, I was doing everything right, the object was being saved. I was wrong about that. The problem was that a variable inside one of the variables inside `MyObject` did not implement `Serializable`